# Windows button to the left

Tags: dconf, window-buttons

So basically, I managed to move my windows button to the left and applied it to the whole system **EXCEPT** the buttons whenever I open the file menu. How do I solve this matter? is this because of the theme that I use? I checked my tweak tool and it shows that the buttons should be on the left.
I look forward to anyone who can answer this.[image: this is the file menu]

Answer (score 1):

Many times changes made to window decoration and theming etc. don't immediately apply to a window of a running instance of an application.

Simply closing and restarting the application (or re-login/rebooting if needed) usually fixes this issue.